# Why Django form_valid is calling twice?

Tags: django, forms

I am using form_valid() to save my data from form and redirecting to specific page using a condition in get_success_url but form_valid() is calling twice.  i saw some people resolved with:

```
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

and

```
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

But found no help with my condition.

**My code from views.py**

```
class CloseMeetingView(LoginRequiredMixin, BSModalUpdateView):
    model = Meeting
    template_name = 'meetings/modal/close_meeting.html'
    form_class = CloseMeetingForm
    success_message = 'Success: Meeting Closed.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CloseMeetingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['meetinginvites'] = RSVPFormSet(
                self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['meetinginvites'] = RSVPFormSet(
                instance=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.closed_date = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        context = self.get_context_data()
        invites = context['meetinginvites']
        with transaction.atomic():
            if invites.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()
                invites.instance = self.object
                invites.save()
                # Notification
                meeting = Meeting.objects.get(pk=self.object.id)
                guests = RSVP.objects.filter(meeting=meeting.id).values_list('responder__user', flat=True)
                users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=guests)
                notify.send(self.request.user, recipient=users, verb="Closed Meeting")
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.request.POST.get('page') == 'meeting':
            id = self.request.POST.get('pass_id')
            return reverse_lazy('Event:meeting-detail', kwargs={'pk': id})
        else:
            return reverse_lazy('Event:allmeeting_view')
```

Comment: `super().form_valid(form)` will save the object again. Do you mean the whole function is being called twice, or just that?

Comment: yes, tried  this also , but nothing changed:
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

Whole form_valid function is called twice

Comment: What's `meetinginvites` here? Is that another form?

Comment: Its a values from inline forms. passed through get_context_data

Comment: Okay. Is the entire `form_valid` function being called twice? In which case, can we see the rest of the view's code?

Comment: yes form_valid get called twice, and i have updated full code in a question

Comment: From what you've got there, it all looks fine. I would check that you're not POSTing twice

Comment: same thing happening with others form_valid too.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing (not using `super().get_form()` at all.) Puzzling. Using `BSModalCreateView`